# rename batch of files

Tags: powershell, rename, file-rename

is there a way rename multiple items in a way that words switch place or move word to the end of the phrase/item name ?

`ABCD 12550.txt` into `12550 ABCD.txt`

im assuming this will start with `Rename-Item`, but what then?

There is a space between words/phrases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Rename-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item) with a [delay-bind script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks#using-delay-bind-script-blocks-with-parameters), in which you can parse and reconstruct each file name.

The following example uses the [`-replace` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) to match and capture the base file name's first word as well as the remaining one(s), and reverses their order (effectively moves the first word to the end):

```bash
Get-ChildItem *.txt |
  Rename-Item -WhatIf -NewName { 
    ($_.BaseName -replace '^(\S+) +(.+)', '$2 $1') + $_.Extension
  }
```

<sup>Note: The [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#whatif) in the command above *previews* the operation. Remove `-WhatIf`  once you're sure the operation will do what you want.</sup>